# Heroku Rails system command fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've deployed my Rails application to Heroku following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 and can open a website like http://severe-mountain-793.herokuapp.com

In my controller, I have a system command that downloads a file into the public directory with  `system('wget', ..., Rails.root.join('public/...'))`. Apparently, from checking the exit status of the command, I realize that the command fails. But I don't know why it fails, and I don't know how to show the output message of the command. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think heroku's filesystem is read-only, so you can't really save files using wget, except if you want to save them inside the '/tmp' folder, where they could be deleted anytime. Moreover, dynos have a 30 seconds timeout, so this would fail for every download which takes more than that interval.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, Ju Liu! 1) Do you know how often files are deleted from the `/tmp` folder? 2) Is there a way to extend the 30 seconds, perhaps by paying them?

Comment: Unfortunately I never tried playing too much with heroku's tmp folder... And AFAIK the 30 seconds is a hard limit which can't be extended :(